# Mocking a list of objects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm learning how to write unit tests and am a little stuck on using Mocks. I'm using Moq for mocking.  I am using the built in test framework that comes with VS 2012.  I can switch to NUnit if that is better (and would solve my problem).  I have a unit of work pattern setup.  The method I'm testing is for resetting a user's password.  I am telling Moq to return a list of users based on a unique code which is what is called in the method I'm testing:

```
var mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        mock.Setup(u => u.UserRepository.Get(t => t.PassResetCode.Equals("test1"), null, "")).Returns(
            new List<User>
        {
            new User { UserId = 4, FirstName = "Test4", LastName = "LastName", Email = "test4@test.com", Salt = salt, Password = pass, AccountConfirmed = true, PassResetCode = "test1", PassResetExpire = new Nullable<DateTime>(DateTime.Now.Add(ts)) },                
        });
```

In the method I'm testing it calls the following:

```
var users = unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(u => u.PassResetCode.Equals(code));
```

As far as I can tell, it is not returning the list of users I'm creating in the test here. Do I need to mock the repository too that is within the Unit of work class?  Or is just mocking the unit of work interface enough?  I can post more of the code if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository accepts delegate and you're setting an expectation to expect particular delegate `t => t.PassResetCode.Equals("test1")`. I think mock inside will compare the passed predicate to this delegate. Different delegate instances will not match with 99.99% probability. You should probably avoid setting up specific constraint for predicate in this particular expectation and use `It.IsAny<>()` instead.

```
var mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
mock.Setup(It.IsAny<Func<User, bool>>(), null, ""), ...).Returns(...)
```

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how to use `It.IsAny<>()` in this case.  Entering what you have it doesn't seem to compile.  Can you add some more to the example or do you need more of my code to do that?  I appreciate the help!

Comment: @ssn771, sorry, had a type in answer. In `It.IsAny<T>` T should be the type of your delegate which you pass to `Get` method.

Comment: It still seems to complain.  This is the error message: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Func<RunnersTrackerDB.User,bool>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<RunnersTrackerDB.User,bool>>`  The method signature for the Get method is: `public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")`

Comment: I got it.  I needed to add `Expression` in there.  So the final version that worked for me in this case was: `mock.Setup(u => u.UserRepository.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>(), null, "")).Returns(...)`  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        mock.Setup(u => u.UserRepository.Get("test1", null, "")).Returns(
            new List<User>
        {
            new User { UserId = 4, FirstName = "Test4", LastName = "LastName", Email = "test4@test.com", Salt = salt, Password = pass, AccountConfirmed = true, PassResetCode = "test1", PassResetExpire = new Nullable<DateTime>(DateTime.Now.Add(ts)) },                
        });
```

You have to be sure you are passing exactly those parameters. Or you can use the syntax `It.IsAny<TYPE>()` for any parameter you do not care. Or you can do `It.Is<TYPE>(condition)` to check for the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/), the issue is the setup method doesn't handle lambdas like that. You would need to use `It.IsAny<Func<T, bool>> ()` as your first argument.